# javascript update lost on first async update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, page-lifecycle

I have an update panel that has a button with a handler:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Updater, this.GetType(), "Hash Update", "UpdateServerData('" +
            avalue + "');", true);
}
```

and a javascript function:

```
function UpdateServerData(val) {
    parent.location.hash = val;
}
```

The first time I click the button after the page loads, the value is written to the location. hash, but is cleared out.  The next click functions the way it should.  I can't figure it out.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go it.  Apparently there is a bug in .Net 3.5 with partial postbacks that removes the Hash.  the answer was here http://magnuskragelund.dk/url-with-hash-mark-changing-after-partial-postback/

thanks for your help though.
Charles